# Get information out of sub-lists in main list elegantly

Tags: python, list, numpy

Ok, so here's my issue. I have a list composed of `N` sub-lists composed of `M` elements (floats) each. So in a general form it looks like this:

```
a_list = [b_list_1, b_list_2, ..., b_list_N]
```

with:

```
b_list_i = [c_float_1, c_float_2, ..., c_float_M]
```

For this example assume `N=9 ; M=3`, so the list looks like this:

```
a = [[1.1, 0.5, 0.7], [0.3, 1.4, 0.2], [0.6, 0.2, 1.], [1.1, 0.5, 0.3], [0.2, 1.1, 0.8], [1.1, 0.5, 1.], [1.2, 0.3, 0.6], [0.6, 0.4, 0.9], [0.6, 0.2, 0.5]]
```

I need to loop through this list identifying those items that *share the same first two floats* as the same item where the third float should be averaged before storing. This means I should check if an item was already identified as being repeated previously, so I do not identify it again as a new item.

To give a more clear idea of what I mean, this is what the output of processing list `a` should look like:

```
a_processed = [[1.1, 0.5, 0.67], [0.3, 1.4, 0.2], [0.6, 0.2, 0.75], [0.2, 1.1, 0.8], [1.2, 0.3, 0.6], [0.6, 0.4, 0.9]]
```

Note that the first item in this new list was identified three times in a (`a[0]`, `a[3]` and `a[5]`) and so it was stored with its third float averaged (`(0.7+0.3+1.)/3. = 0.67`). The second item was not repeated in `a` so it was stored as is. The third item was found twice in `a` (`a[2]` and `a[8]`) and stored with its third float averaged (`(1.+0.5)/2.=0.75`). The rest of the items in the new list were not found as repeated in `a` so they were also stored with no modifications.

Since I know updating/modifying a list while looping through it is not recommended, I opted to use several temporary lists. This is the code I came up with:

```
import numpy as np

a = [[1.1, 0.5, 0.7], [0.3, 1.4, 0.2], [0.6, 0.2, 1.], [1.1, 0.5, 0.3],
     [0.2, 1.1, 0.8], [1.1, 0.5, 1.], [1.2, 0.3, 0.6], [0.6, 0.4, 0.9],
[0.6, 0.2, 0.5]]

# Final list.
a_processed = []

# Holds indexes of elements to skip.
skip_elem = []

# Loop through all items in a.
for indx, elem in enumerate(a):
    temp_average = []
    temp_average.append(elem)        
    # Only process if not found previously.
    if indx not in skip_elem:
        for indx2, elem2 in enumerate(a[(indx+1):]):
            if elem[0] == elem2[0] and elem[1] == elem2[1]:
                temp_average.append(elem2)
                skip_elem.append(indx2+indx+1)

        # Store 1st and 2nd floats and averaged 3rd float.
        a_processed.append([temp_average[0][0], temp_average[0][1],
                            round(np.mean([i[2] for i in temp_average]),2)])
```

This code works, but I'm wondering if there might be a more elegant/pythonic way of doing this. It just looks too convoluted (Fortran-esque I'd say) as is.

Comment: This might be better on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: do you need a specific order in `a_processed`? Or any order of elements will do?

Comment: Any order will do, I can rearrange them later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can certainly make your code more concise and easier to read by using `defaultdict` to create a dictionary from the first two elements in each sublist to all the third items:

```
from collections import defaultdict
nums = defaultdict(list)
for arr in a:
    key = tuple(arr[:2]) # make the first two floats the key
    nums[key].append( arr[2] ) # append the third float for the given key

a_processed = [[k[0], k[1], sum(vals)/len(vals)] for k, vals in nums.items()]
```

Using this, I get the same output as you (albeit in a different order):

```
[[0.2, 1.1, 0.8], [1.2, 0.3, 0.6], [0.3, 1.4, 0.2], [0.6, 0.4, 0.9], [1.1, 0.5, 0.6666666666666666], [0.6, 0.2, 0.75]]
```

If the order of `a_processed` is an issue, you can use an [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects), as pointed out by @DSM.

Comment: Another way to preserve the order would be to use an `OrderedDict` instead of a `defaultdict`, and use `nums.setdefault(key, []).append(arr[2])`.  Then iterating over `nums.items()` would give the key, value pairs in order of first appearance.

Answer (score 4):

For comparison, here's the [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) approach.  If this is really a data processing problem behind the scenes, then you can save yourself a lot of time that way.

```
>>> a
[[1.1, 0.5, 0.7], [0.3, 1.4, 0.2], [0.6, 0.2, 1.0], [1.1, 0.5, 0.3], [0.2, 1.1, 0.8], [1.1, 0.5, 1.0], [1.2, 0.3, 0.6], [0.6, 0.4, 0.9], [0.6, 0.2, 0.5]]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(a)
>>> df.groupby([0,1]).mean()
                2
0   1            
0.2 1.1  0.800000
0.3 1.4  0.200000
0.6 0.2  0.750000
    0.4  0.900000
1.1 0.5  0.666667
1.2 0.3  0.600000
```

This problem is common enough that it's a one-liner.  You can use named columns, compute a host of other useful statistics, handle missing data, etc.

Comment: This looks amazingly simple but unfortunately I can't make use of `pandas` currently (not installed in the cluster I use) I'll definitely check this package out though. Thank you!